# No file chosen even when file is chosen - mvc

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm updating record so I'm viewing an Edit page that I created, when I change the values and choose another file to be uploaded rather than previous and press update button, the error I see is "no file chosen" below the choose file control. Why is it so when I'm choosing the file.

I'm using the following code for the file upload:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
        </div>
    </div>
```

While creating this record same code is used and it works fine, then what could be the problem when trying to update a record?

Comment: What is the data type of the `File` property of the model?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

The only thing if you're facing the same problem to do is check if your .cshtml file does have this line if not replace your @html.beginForm with something similar to following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Stations", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made File property as Required. so you are facing that issues.
Remove  [Required] attribute from File.

[Required] **<--Remove this attribute**
public IEnumerable File { get; set; }